# ENOTCONN with piping to process.stdout and process.stderr

Tags: javascript, node.js

Created an access and error pipe or a writable stream for console.log or console.error to be written to a file stream.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var access = fs.createWriteStream('/node.access.log', { flags: 'a' });
var error = fs.createWriteStream('/node.error.log', { flags: 'a' });
process.stdout.pipe(access); // redirect stdout / stderr
process.stderr.pipe(error);
```

my expectation is whenever I do `console.log` or `console.error` it's written to the file output stream.

I'm having an error

```
Error: read ENOTCONN
    at Socket._read (net.js:528:20)
    at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:457:10)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:936:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) {
  errno: 'ENOTCONN',
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because process.stdout is a writable stream, not a readable (or duplex), so its impossible to bind to its events.

You can override globally process.stdout with a duplex stream (after you are keeping the  original stream in another global variable, otherwise you will need to write to file descriptor IO, using net